# Training DLib Pedestrian HoG detector results in bad detector

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, camera, computer-vision, dlib

I've been trying to train my own pedestrian detector using DLib's training tools (basically a modified version of this: [train_object_detector.py](http://dlib.net/train_object_detector.py.html)). I've tried using the INRIA and MIT pedestrian databases and have had no luck.

The visualization of my detector tends to look something like this:

[image]

For reference, DLib's included face detector looks like this:

[image]

I've tried using varying sample sizes (5-1000) as well as varying levels of C (1-1,000,000,000).

I'm not really sure what to try next.

Comment: What is your training error and validation error on INRIA and MIT databases?

Comment: Other man already trained it. https://github.com/sturkmen72/dlib_pedestrian_detection

Comment: @AmitayNachmani extremely low. Off the top of my head, something like 0.04 for the test set. The training set was a perfect 1.

Comment: @Evgeni Thanks, I saw that - it works decently well and I'm interested to see his more detailed information that is coming soon. I don't want to use someone elses though, I want to be able to train my own well.

Comment: Dlib's detector is not reliable in a situations of pose change. Pedestrians are changing their poses very often. So I recommend you train several detectors and join them into one like dlib's face detector is. And if you are telling that you results are bad - give us full info about your training settins, dataset properties and testing results

Answer (score 2):

you can try the output [svm file](https://github.com/sturkmen72/dlib_pedestrian_detection) that i trained before. 
for using it you should to know window size

```
scanner.set_detection_window_size(48, 96);
```

you will find training.xml and image files that i used to train the detector.
i compared it with OpenCV's HOGDescriptor ( DefaultPeopleDetector ). OpenCV works slower but obviously more successfull.

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look at this soon and keep an eye on your repo

Comment: I appreciate the detector svm file but am still very curious about the settings and images you chose to use.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android/tree/master/data) you will find another trained detector